# Issue with gulp-iconfont

Tags: gulp, icon-fonts

I've already raised issue [here](https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-iconfont/issues/146) to which author says, it's misconfiguration.

My issues is that my configuration looks correct but it's not generating icons properly.

Getting this using `gulp-iconfont`:

[image]

Getting this using [iconmoon website](https://icomoon.io/)

[image]